# Get integer part of a decimal

Tags: php

I need to get integer part of decimal value

Now I'm using floor but not working as I want

```
function getInt( $value ) {
  return floor($value);
}

echo getInt(1.2*3); --> return 3 - as I want
echo getInt(2.3*100); --> return 229 - I want 230
echo getInt((4.56*100)/12); --> return 37 - I want 38
```

Seems floor not working on integer number?

Comment: 1.2 * 3=3.6 .so you want 3 or 4.and also 2.3*100=230.you want 229?

Comment: Float values are not always what you expect.

Comment: use intval function if you dont mind signs